# Convert music file to byte array c# like matlab

Tags: c#, matlab, file-io

I would like to convert any music file into a byte array and print the result in c# just like in MATLAB.

I tried this;

```
System.IO.FileStream _FileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(_FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
System.IO.BinaryReader _BinaryReader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(_FileStream);

long _TotalBytes = new System.IO.FileInfo(_FileName).Length;
_Buffer = _BinaryReader.ReadBytes((Int32)_TotalBytes);
```

And the code to print to console:

```
Console.WriteLine( byteArrayToString(fileToByteArray("Penguins.jpg")) );
```

where the method's code is:

```
private static string byteArrayToString(byte[] p)
{
    string result = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(p);
    return result;
}
```

When I run this code, console becomes crazy with irrelevant characters, however I would like to have an array like MATLAB's output.

How should I do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, this code can be simplified to `File.ReadAllBytes(_FileName)`...

Comment: And where's the code that prints to the console? You're only showing how you load the data from the file

Comment: Code is:

Console.WriteLine(byteArrayToString(fileToByteArray("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures/Penguins.jpg")));

and the method's code is:

private static string byteArrayToString(byte[] p)
        {
            string result = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(p);
            return result;
        }

Comment: don't post it in a comment, its really hard to read... edit your question instead

Comment: @Can, What does the output in MatLab look like?

Comment: Las time i checked jpg wasn't a music file format :D

Comment: :D when I try with mp3 file it will take very long and crashes therefore I tried with jpeg.

in matlab the output is all numbers, but in this output, it is very complicated, for example:

~ÌĞ~Ò­ììîVÃÅ3=Æ•q7ú§vO)Ù}‰şë"W¼Q@öğOWú—ØeğÕ¥„;¶5õÆ§oå/û+îoûâ¿Zü%áè¼%á-C·Å¥ØÛÙ+ÿ Ê‰ÿ d­Z(QE(¢Š ).....

Comment: That is what binary files tend to look like if you convert them to ascii. If you want the output to be numbers then don't convert the binary file into an ascii string.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the byte array of any file just do the following:

```
byte[] byteArrayFile = File.ReadAllBytes(source);
//source is the path to the file
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want characters? If you just want the numbers, build a string with the numbers. I don't know matlabs format, but say for a row vector like [N1,N2,N3]

```
private static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] p)
{
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
     for(int i=0; i<p.Length; i++)
     {
          sb.Append(p[i]);
          if (i < p.Length - 1)
              sb.Append(',');
     }
     sb.Append("]");
     return sb.ToString();
}
```